# git modified file keeps coming up after checking out branch

Tags: git, git-checkout

I have a modified file on the master branch.

I do a `git checkout myfile`, check `git status` and the master branch is up-to-date with no modified files.

But when I checkout another branch and come back with `git checkout master` the modified file shows up again. I don´t know why, I even cleaned the stash, but still, whenever I switch back to master, that file shows up as modified again.

Anyone a hint how to solve that?

Comment: what kind of difference of file do you see? Maybe one branch has line endings normalization and other not.

Comment: BTW proper command is: `git checkout -- filename`

Comment: no, it´not about line endings. it´s real changes.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any `.gitattributes` which could declare a smudge content filter driver: that would be a script executed automatically on checkout, which could modify a file (or files).

Try also a `git reset --hard`, before checkout branch/checkout master, to see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks, just read this too late. I could solve it by deleting my local copy and cloning the repo again. The problem did not come up again.